# Property 'hot' is missing in type 'Module'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

hello everyone when i use @types/node for aws-cognito-identity provider
i get the following error.

```
Class 'Module' incorrectly implements interface 'NodeModule'.
        Property 'hot' is missing in type 'Module'.
```

Thanks for your help. I think it conflicts with @types/webpack-env

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there might be a breaking change between `@types/node@8.0.26` and `@types/node@8.0.27` causing this error, probably in conjunction with `@types/webpack-env@1.13.0` (my version at least).

Rolling back to 8.0.26 (adding `"@types/node": "8.0.26"` to my `package.json`) seems to fix it for now.

Edit:
Looking a bit closer, it seems this has been noticed and an issue raise:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/19601 + fix PR is open:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/19602

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying something like, `module.hot` Then you can use it as `(module as any).hot`. This works for me.